# How to read and display columns and sub columns from an excel file into a data frame using RStudio

Tags: r, dataframe

I tried reading an excel file where I need to read sub columns too, but not getting a way to resolve this. Can anybody give me some hints to work on it.

The excel file contains data as,

```
Row1 : | Sl No.   |      X         |     Y    |    Z    |
Row2 : |          |  a    |   b    |  c  | d  |         |
Row3 : |   1      |  34   |   67   | 175 | 45 |  125    |
```

After importing I can see the data as

```
Sl. No.    X    ...3        Y       ...5       Z
  NA       a       b        c          d       NA
  1        12     34       56         78       55
```

But I need it to be like,

```
Sl. No.     X              Y            Z
          a     b       c          d    
   1     12     34     56         78    55
```

Please need your assistance on this

Comment: You cannot have multiple headers in R.

Answer (score 0):

Though I can hardly think the use of such a structure (in the form you specified), here is one way to go about getting what you want. Since, you mentioned that you're reading an `xls` or `xlsx` file, I'm going to use `xlsx` package.

```r
library("xlsx")
# read the data frame
df <- read.xlsx("my_file.xlsx", sheetName="Sheet1", header = FALSE)
#df <- read.xlsx("my_file.xls", sheetName="Sheet1", header = FALSE)
#[1] df <- read.csv("~/my_file.csv",  header = FALSE)
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
#     X1 X2   X3  X4   X5   X6
# 1 S1.No  X <NA>   Y <NA>    Z
# 2  <NA>  a    b   c    d <NA>
# 3     1 12   34 175   45  125

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

# replace NA's with empty string (This is not required for the csv file)
df <- sapply(df, as.character)
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
#       X1      X2   X3   X4    X5   X6   
# [1,] "S1.No" "X"  NA   "Y"   NA   "Z"  
# [2,] NA      "a"  "b"  "c"   "d"  NA   
# [3,] "1"     "12" "34" "175" "45" "125"
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

# replace NA with empty string
df[is.na(df)] <- " "
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
#       X1      X2   X3   X4    X5   X6   
# [1,] "S1.No" "X"  " "  "Y"   " "  "Z"  
# [2,] " "     "a"  "b"  "c"   "d"  " "  
# [3,] "1"     "12" "34" "175" "45" "125"

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Coerce df to a data frame 
df <- as.data.frame(df)
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
#      X1 X2 X3  X4 X5  X6
# 1 S1.No  X      Y      Z
# 2        a  b   c  d    
# 3     1 12 34 175 45 125

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Use the first row instead of the auto generated header
# This is the second action for the csv file
colnames(df) <- as.character(unlist(df[1,]))
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   S1.No  X      Y      Z
# 1 S1.No  X      Y      Z
# 2        a  b   c  d    
# 3     1 12 34 175 45 125

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Finally remove the first row 
# This is the third action for the csv file 
df = df[-1,]

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   S1.No  X      Y      Z
# 2        a  b   c  d    
# 3     1 12 34 175 45 125
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This gives you a data frame which you can `tidy` further.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort, but the result I am getting post running your code is   
        a   b   c   d 
    2  1 12 34 56 78 55
Not as 
    S1.No  X        Y        Z
 2           a  b    c    d    
 3     1  12 34  175 45 125.

 I mean to say, there is no "Sl. No.  X  Y  Z" row in final result

Comment: @Vin I'm not sure what's has happened at your end, but I have annotated the output of the script depending on your input so you can trace the output partly. See my edits.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I am trying to find out a way still. 
I will let you know if I find it :)