# How to read and process columns with sub columns from an excel/.csv/any file?

Tags: r, dataframe

I tried reading an Excel file where I need to read sub columns too, but not getting a way to resolve this.

The Excel file contains data as,

```
 | Sl No.   |     Sales 1    |   Sales 2    |    % Change  |
 |          | 1 Qtr | % Qtr  | 2 Qtr| % Qtr |              |
 |   1      |  134  |   67   | 175  |  74   |     12.5     |
```

After importing I can see the data as

```
 | Sl No.   |Sales 1| ...3   |Sales 2 | ...5  |    % Change  |
 |    NA    | 1 Qtr | % Qtr  | 2 Qtr  | % Qtr |      NA      |
 |   1      |  134  |   67   | 175    |  74   |     12.5     |
```

I tried several ways to merge "Sales 1 & ...3 and Sales 2 & ...5" and keep 1 Qtr,% Qtr,2 Qtr,% Qtr as sub columns, but unable to do so

I need it to be like,

```
 | Sl No.   |     Sales 1    |   Sales 2    |    % Change  |
 |          | 1 Qtr | % Qtr  | 2 Qtr| % Qtr |              |
 |   1      |  134  |   67   | 175  |  74   |     12.5     |
```

Comment: How is it different from your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57820798/how-to-read-and-display-columns-and-sub-columns-from-an-excel-file-into-a-data-f

Comment: Haven't find an answer for that yet. So, here placing a question with some more facts. Please assist if you can.

Comment: As data object (data.frame) you can't have such columns, but as a presentation of data have a look at [DT package](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/).

Comment: Provide example data: `dput(head(myImportedExcelFile))`.

Comment: I have gone through that initially @zx8754 but that creates an image which is out of my scope, the requirement for me is to push the data into a database.

Comment: I don't know any database that can store such format. I think your expected output is not database friendly.

Comment: What does the database table you are pushing to look like? And what are the means of making such push?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, R doesn't allow for multiple colnames. So probably the easiest thing you can do using base R is combining the colnames and then getting rid of the first line.

```
library(openxlsx)

x <- read.xlsx("your_file.xlsx")

#   Sl.No Sales.1   X3 Sales.2   X5 %Change
# 1    NA   1 Qtr %Qtr   2 Qtr %Qtr      NA
# 2     1     134   67     175   74    12.5

colnames(x) <- paste0(colnames(x),ifelse(is.na(x[1,]),"",paste0(" - ", x[1,])))
x <- x[-1,]

#   Sl.No Sales.1 - 1 Qtr X3 - %Qtr Sales.2 - 2 Qtr X5 - %Qtr %Change
# 2     1             134        67             175        74    12.5

colnames(x)
# [1] "Sl.No" "Sales.1 - 1 Qtr" "X3 - %Qtr" "Sales.2 - 2 Qtr" "X5 - %Qtr" "%Change"
```

Comment: I have done the same way initially but due to some reasons client is expecting the report in the same way that I mentioned at the end of my question.
Will there be any hopes?

Comment: You could export it again to excel and change the colnames manually or you can split the colnames up, inserting the first line like before, as last step in the process. Unfortunately, there may not be better solutions.

Comment: I agree with you @alex_555 but the fact is -  this sort of file comes to us through a job, and it is needed to be furnished and then pushed to a data base through R programming. So the idea of changing manually in the file will not work.

Comment: Sometimes I have to overcome the same issues. I personally prefer combining the colnames and separating them again in the end. It's not a pretty solution, but it's probably the only thing that works (dependent on the database). Another solution could be to change the output format from the database if you've access to it. Long format could be an idea for your dataset to avoid multiple headers.